# Unity C# how to make one variable equal another without using static keyword

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static

So I have a basic problem in unity:

```
public int A = 0;
int B = A;
```

This code throws an 'A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property' error.

So I could do this:

```
public static int A = 0;
int B = A;
```

Which works, but then variable 'A' will not show up on the inspector. Can I have my cake and eat it too, having both a variable that can equal another and having it show up in the inspector? Thank you.

Comment: Static method cannot access non static field, if you want A to be non static, then the method using A must also be non static, the class too can't be static. You need to post your full source code for others to suggest changes.

Comment: @Rosdi Kasim The class is not static.

Comment: David is right, you can not give the value of a var to a var before `start` or `awake`, you need `start` to initialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int A = 0;
public int B;

void Start() {
    B = A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutions that **could** have worked in C#:

```
public const int A = 9;
int B = A;
```

And

```
public static int A = 9;
int B = A;
```

`Static` and `constant` variables  cannot be displayed in Unity Editor. If you want to assign **A** to **B**, and still make it to show in the Editor, you have to do this in a function.

If you want **B** to always have the-same value as **A** throuout the program runtime,

```
public int A;
int B;

//Initialize A to B
void Start()
{
    B = A;
}

//Make B always equals to A 
void Update()
{
    B = A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the class is not static, your fields will not be initialized until you actually create an instance of the class for example.

```
public class Bot
{
    public int a = 0;
    public int b;
    //If you try this it will not work
    //public int b = a;

    public Bot()
    {
        //This will work because once you create Bot, all fields will be initialized
        this.b = a;
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    //Once you create the class the Bot constructor will be called automatially
    Bot botty1 = new Bot();
}
```